# Heroku "demo" environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app deployed on Heroku with staging and production environments. I need another deployment, a "demo" one, which acts like production, but has a separate database. Does heroku have a smarter way to achieve this than simply adding another custom environment?

Thank you!